# export data as csv in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to export data as a csv in a react app without a library. My code looks like so:

```
 const download = () => {
    const dummyData = 'rahul,delhi,accountsdept\n';
    const csvContent = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${dummyData}`;
    const encodedURI = encodeURI(csvContent);
    window.open(encodedURI);
}
```

And then I have a button with this download function as an onclick.

```
      <button onClick={download}>
        Generate Vehicle Offer Prices
      </button>
```

This is supposed to work in vanilla javascript, is there a reason it doesn't work in react?

Here's a sandbox with the code not working in react [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-cloud-5jldc?file=/src/App.js)

Here's a link with it working in vanilla js [vanilla](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-payne-nsnnw?file=/src/index.js:300-477)

Answer (score 2):

It is working actually, look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-jepsen-xhnly?file=/src/App.js:0-497):

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const download = () => {
    const dummyData = "rahul,delhi,accountsdept\n";
    const csvContent = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${dummyData}`;
    const encodedURI = encodeURI(csvContent);
    window.open(encodedURI);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={download}>Generate Vehicle Offer Prices</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hm, when I click on the link nothing happens on my computer, it just rerenders. Does it download for you?

Comment: yes it downloads. im using chrome, and you?

Comment: @devdoingit you can use window.location.href = encodedUri instead of window.open

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NPM library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv

**Example**

```
import {CSVLink, CSVDownload} from 'react-csv';

const csvData =[
  ['rahul', 'delhi', 'accountsdept']  
];
<CSVLink data={csvData} >Download me</CSVLink>
```

**OR**

```
<CSVDownload data={csvData} target="_blank" />
```

Comment: beware, react-csv hasn't been maintained since 2021